# Función Oracle PL/SQL que retorne JSon para WebService en MVC 5.0

Tags: json, oracle, webservice, asp.net-mvc-5, plsql

Buen Día:

**Problema**

Me gustaría saber si existen comandos que pueda utilizar a nivel de base de datos para armar una consulta directo en formato Json o debo armar la consulta y lógica manualmente creando mis propias funciones de interpretación Json y/o xml.

**Contexto**

Necesito hacer un WebService en MVC 5.0 con autenticación en LDAP que lea una base de datos Oracle (hasta ahí la conexión se establece).

El inconveniente es que la base debe tener un package que entre una de sus funciones debe tener una que retorne ciertos datos de la base pero en cadena en formato Json para que el WebService lea y arroje estos datos ya sea mediante un método REST o POST.

El nivel de encriptación debe estar dentro de la base de datos y no dentro de la capa de la aplicación o web service por eso mi consulta es saber si existen comandos que pueda utilizar a nivel de base de datos para armar la consulta directo en formato Json o debo armar la consulta y lógica manualmente creando mis propias funciones de interpretación Json y/o xml.

Muchas gracias por sus respuestas.

Saludos.

Comment: Deberías indicar la versión de Oracle.

Comment: Disculpen, la versión de Oracle utilizada es:
Oracle Database 12c Enterprise Edition Release 12.1.0.2.0 - 64bit
PL/SQL Release 12.1.0.2.0
"CORE 12.1.0.2.0"
TNS for Linux: Version 12.1.0.2.0
NLSRTL Version 12.1.0.2.0